# Does there exist a general expression for this product of binomials as a multivariate polynomial?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

Consider the product
$$
\prod_{i=1}^n (1-x_i) = (1-x_1)\times\cdots\times (1-x_n)
$$
Is there a general expression for this product as a multivariate polynomial? That is, can the coefficients $a_j$ and the functions $f_j$ (which are monomials) in the following summation be determined without computing the product above?
$$
\prod_{i=1}^n (1-x_i) = \sum_{j=0}^{2^n - 1} a_j \cdot f_j(x_1,\dots,x_n)
$$

Comment: I suggest that you expand the product for $n=2, 3, 4$. Can you detect a pattern? – The number of terms should be $2^n$, not $n^2$.

Comment: @MartinR Yes, I think I see a pattern. The coefficient for the $j$th term in the summation is $+1$ if the number of terms in the monomial $f_j(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ is even, and it is $-1$ if the number of terms in the monomial $f_j(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ is odd. Is this what you were hinting at?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on @MartinR's comment, we have that
$$
a_j = \begin{cases}+1, &\textrm{$\phi(j)$ even} \\ -1, &\textrm{$\phi(j)$ odd}\end{cases}
$$
where $\phi(j)$ is the number of $1$'s in the binary of expansion of $j$ (see [here](https://mathoverflow.net/q/161402/311484) and [here](https://oeis.org/A000120) for a closed-form expression for $\phi(j)$) and
$$
f_j(x_1,\dots,x_n) = \prod_{i=1}^n x_i^{\alpha_i(j)}
$$
where $\alpha_i(j)$ is the $i$th bit in the binary expansion of $j$ when $j$ ranges from $0$ to $2^{n}-1$. For example,
$$
\begin{align}
(1-x_1)(1-x_2)(1-x_3) = \underbrace{1}_{j = 0 = 000} - \underbrace{x_3}_{j=1=001} - \underbrace{x_2}_{j=2=010} + \underbrace{x_2x_3}_{j=3=011} - \underbrace{x_1}_{j=4=100} + \underbrace{x_1x_3}_{j=5=101} + \underbrace{x_1x_2}_{j=6=110} - \underbrace{x_1x_2x_3}_{j=7=111}
\end{align}
$$
Unfortunately, I do not yet have a formal proof of this for the general $n$.

Comment: Is there a reason you choose $f_j(x_1,\dots,x_n) = \prod_{i=1}^n x_i^{\alpha_i(j)}$? Unless there is a particular reason (perhaps the context this problem arised in) that you are considering binary, I don't think it is particularly necessary. For example, your definition of $a_j$ can be more simply stated as $a_j = +1$ if the $j$th term has an odd number of factors (such as $x_3$ or $x_1x_2x_3$) and $a_j = -1$ if the $j$th term has an even number of factors (such as $x_1x_3$ or $x_1x_2x_3x_4$). Hopefully, this definition of $a_j$ is evident from my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Replace $1$ with $x$ to get $P(x) = \prod_{i=1}^n (x-x_i) = (x-x_1)\cdots(x-x_n)$. There are well-known formulas known as [Vieta's formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas) that can determine the coefficients in terms of these roots. Then, we can evaluate it at $x = 1$ to get the desired result.

#### In Action

We want to find coefficients $a_1,\dots,a_n$ to write $P(x) = a_n x^n+ \dots + a_1x + a_0$. It is easy to see that $a_n = 1$. By Vieta's formulas, we have $$\sum_{1 \leq i_1 \leq i_2 \leq \dots \leq i_k \leq n} x_{i_1}x_{i_2}\cdots x_{i_k} = (-1)^k\frac{a_{n-k}}{a_n} = (-1)^ka_{n-k}.$$

Now, evaluating at $x=1$, we have
$$P(1) = \prod_{i=1}^n (1-x_i) = \sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k\sum_{1 \leq i_1 \leq i_2 \leq \dots \leq i_k \leq n} x_{i_1}x_{i_2}\cdots x_{i_k}.$$

This means that the coefficient is $+1$ if the number of factors $k$ is even (such as $x_1x_3$ or $x_1x_2x_3x_4$) and $-1$ if $k$ is odd (such as $x_3$ or $x_1x_2x_3$).

#### Note

Depending on why you want to determine the coefficients, this may or may not be useful to you, but I will just leave it here in case someone else finds it useful.

Comment: I'm not sure how this helps, since it seems that Vieta's formulas apply to univariate polynomials only, while my case is a multivariate polynomial.

Comment: @mhdadk We can view the polynomial in my answer as a univariate polynomial in $x$ and view $x_1,\dots,x_n$ as roots of the polynomial. Then, we can apply Vieta's formulas. After evaluating at $x=1$, we end up with a sum of monomials in $x_1,\dots,x_n$.

Comment: Could you show this in action in your answer?

Comment: Thanks for the edit. When you write "Now, evaluating at $x=1$...", what do you mean by this? What exactly are you evaluating at $x=1$? It's not clear from the expression above this line where $x$ is.

Comment: @mhdadk I am evaluating $P(x) = a_n x^n+ \dots + a_1x + a_0$ at $x = 1$ and also substituting my expression for $a_{n-k}$.